# ADO FieldByName('X').AsCurrency returns 0

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe8

Delphi XE8 and SQLServer 2017.

I have a query (`TADOQuery`) connected to a SQLServer database. After opening the dataset (`TADOQuery.Open`), if I call `TADOQuery.FieldByName('X').AsCurrency` it returns 0, but if I call `TADOQuery.FieldByName('X').AsFloat` it returns `12.65` (correct value). Looking at the specific field in the table, the type is `numeric(18,4)`. What's wrong?

This code runs the **otherthing**:

```pascal
with TADOQuery1 do
begin
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('select X from Table1');
  Open;
  if FieldByName('X').AsCurrency > 0 then  // <- Here is the problem
    do something
  else
    do otherthing;
end;
```

This code runs the **something**:

```pascal
with TADOQuery1 do
begin
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('select X from Table1');
  Open;
  if FieldByName('X').AsFloat > 0 then  // <- Here is the problem
    do something
  else
    do otherthing;
end;
```

Comment: what ODBC driver do use? (share your connectionstring)

Comment: Are you sure that your `FieldByName('X').AsCurrency` returns 0? Your code will execute `otherthing` if it returns 0 or any other negative number.

Comment: The connection string is `Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Password=123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=LEO-PC;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=GasStorage;Workstation ID=LEO-PC;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;MARS Connection=True;DataTypeCompatibility=0;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=READWRITE`

Comment: Yes, FieldByName('X").AsCurrency returns 0 and FieldByName('X').AsFloat returns the correct value

Answer (score 2):

Cannot reproduce this behavior.

here is a MRE, amount is a numeric(18,4) in table Tbl_test :

```
program SO68004040;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  ActiveX,
  AdoDb,
  System.SysUtils;


var
  DbConn : TADOConnection;
  Qry    : TADOQuery;

begin
  Coinitialize(nil);
  try
    DbConn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
    Qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
    try
     Qry.Connection := DbConn;
     DbConn.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=TestCustomer;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; ';
     DbConn.Connected := True;
     Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Tbl_test';
     Qry.Open;
     while not Qry.Eof do
      begin
       Writeln(Format('AsCurrency: %.4f', [Qry.FieldByName('amount').AsCurrency]));
       Writeln(Format('AsFloat: %.4f', [Qry.FieldByName('amount').AsFloat]));
       Qry.Next;
      end;
    finally
     Qry.Free;
     DbConn.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  CoUninitialize();
  Readln;
end.
```